# The exception raised from TJvHidDeviceController.OnRemoval - how to handle it on application level?

Tags: delphi, exception

Subj.
Windows 7, Delphi XE7, JVCL Version 3.49.
Exceptions, raised from event handlers for `TJvHidDeviceController` - can be handled locally in this handlers via `try catch end`.
Ok.
But can not handle this exceptions on application level, for sample - at `ApplicationEvents.OnException`.
**Update: can not handle this exception outside OnRemove() event handler.**
It just losts somewhere.
Below minimal example for reproduce problem.

```delphi
unit uFormMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, JvComponentBase, JvHidControllerClass, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    HidCtl: TJvHidDeviceController;
    procedure HidCtlArrival(AHidDev: TJvHidDevice);
    procedure HidCtlRemoval(AHidDev: TJvHidDevice);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormMain.HidCtlArrival(AHidDev: TJvHidDevice);
begin
  Writeln(Format('+ OnArrival: "%s"', [AHidDev.ProductName]));
end;

procedure TFormMain.HidCtlRemoval(AHidDev: TJvHidDevice);
begin
  Writeln(Format('- OnRemoval: "%s"', [AHidDev.ProductName]));

  // For Exception test just unplug an USB-Mouse or USB-Keyboard
  raise Exception.Create('Exception test from HidCtlRemoval');

  // ... and no any Message Boxes
  // and OnArrival / OnRemoval not worked properly after first exception
end;

end.
```

Comment: I don't see an ApplicationEvents component anywhere, or an OnException event handler for that component.

Comment: Also, if you don't handle the exception locally, you can't continue beyond that point, because it won't return from ApplicationEvents.OnException to the HidCtlRemoval event.

Comment: After this exception program show UB.
Compare this with exception from an TButton.OnClick handler. It handled ok outside OnClick. And no any UB.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your last comment means.

Comment: @Karagy Don't use abbreviations that only exist in your language. Do you mean an AV (Access Violation)? Also please consult someone who can help you with English.

Comment: I mean Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: It is likely that the exception is caught somewhere, either in JVCL or in your own code. You could find where using the debugger. First add all jvcl source code to your project, then run under debugger and when the exception is raised, hit F8. You should see where the exception handling occurs.

Comment: Adding all jvcl source code to my project - it is beyond my skills. It seems - local exception  handling - acceptable solution for me. Even in each event handler.

Comment: It’s normal to handle the exception in the event, but if you realy want the exception to roll into the Application.OnException event handler, you can call it from within the `except` clause using `ApplicationHandleException(Self)`.